# Admin slow on Postlist (over 30k Posts in Database)

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-admin

we have a Site with around 20k Posts in the normal postlist and another 10k in other CPT.
The custom post types work really fast, but the normal Post List doesn't.
I assume that might be because the server aggregates how many posts are published, how many are mine and how many are deleted, but I'm not really sure about that.

Any idea how to limit what is being queried - I looked in google how to remove sections from the query but all I find is css "hacks" to not display the filters, not how to remove them from the query.

if you have any other ideas, please let me know.

Comment: While this is probably too specific for this site since it is not a general WP issue - have you tried using a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ to identify what is actually slow?

Comment: Yes, I have, and it is not the query itself - I assume because the normal Post List has so many segmentations to count it's the number of queries. So I want to reduce that.
The Custom Posttype works fine, so I don't really understand what it is.

Comment: How many posts are set to display in one page in Screen Options?

Comment: "it is not the query itself" - then what is it? Are you sure you shouldn't be showing some code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this filter can help you to modify the query for the specific post type and inside wp-admin

as per the documentation, this filter is called before the query is executed so you can modify/optimize the query with the help of this filter.

```
do_action_ref_array( 'pre_get_posts', WP_Query $query )
```

further reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

Comment: Perfect, thank you!
I will try out what it is and then get back here